# How to remove the visor of a POC Trabec helmet?

Tags: road-bike, mountain-bike, helmets

The title says it all. I feel like I'm missing something, but I can't find help anywhere on Google, and I don't want to break the visor.

Here's a link
http://www.pocsports.com/us/products/trabec/10501.html

Comment: how did you get on with this visor?  In SE its totally acceptable to answer your own question.

Comment: I actually haven't removed it. I like it for mtb, but I wanted to remove it for my road rides. My wife bought me another helmet for road though...

Answer (score 4):

You sure that's removable?  On the POC website, it lists that as "Adjustable visor", not "removable visor"...

Comment: "The visor is adjustable and can be removed and re-attached easily." I've seen comments like these from https://www.singletracks.com/blog/mtb-gear/poc-trabec-race-helmet-review/ and elsewhere around Google

Comment: I know with the other helmet brands my work carries, they are usually just tensioned into the shell of the helmet with a couple clips, and you just pull at the corners and they come off.  But I've never had experience with that brand, so I don't know if that one works the same way

Comment: Your provided link is a review from 2011.  It's entirely plausible that the company has changed their design in the past 6 years to remove the removal/reattach technique.